# Is there actually a right and wrong way to deal with major imbalance in logistic regression (or other models, really)?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, oversampling, smote, under-sampling

I have seen a lot of different advice on how to deal with imbalance, and I get that it can be case-specific.  But I learned in school that SMOTE oversampling or undersampling were basically the ways to fix this, and now in the real world these methods seem to be introducing a lot of problems with bias and uninterpretable probability.  I have done a lot of research and also looked at weighting the model, or just changing the threshold downstream.  Every time I think I have a good solution to my classification problem (right now trying to find a model for classifiying interested leads for sales when the sales are 12x lower than non-sales), I do more research and run into someone on a blog insisting that this is the wrong way - is there a right and a wrong? I have a large dataset and when I do nothing, the accuracy is great..but it predicts almost all non-sales, of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) If not, what questions remain? You may be interested in some of the links in my profile, several of which relate to this topic.